# Remove specific item from AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I know it is possible to remove a whole key from asyncStorage like this `AsyncStorage.removeItem('users');`
but how can I remove a specific item from inside the users key, for example remove `id` `2` from users key:

```
[{id:1, user:A}, {id:2, user:B}, {id:3, user:C}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `AsyncStorage.setItem('users', someOtherObject)` will override the existing object in the store. So, just read, alter and write back.

```
const users = await AsyncStorage.getItem('users');
const alteredUsers = users.splice(users.findIndex(x => x.id === someId), 1);
AsyncStorage.setItem('users', alteredUsers);
```